# Hot to achive Google+ profile listview layout?

Tags: android, listview, layout, tabs, google-plus

I have a task at work to create view that shows a list of items and it is controlled by the tab. At the top of the list there must be a header that displays an image. Tabs needs to be below the header image. When user scrolls tabs and header image moves up until header goes out of the screen. Tabs should never go out of the screen, they should stick at the top of the list view all the time in order to allow user to navigate between 3 lists.

I found something similar at google+ profile view. The image shows an example how it should look like. Dose anyone know how to achieve that on android.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81459779/question.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). Install the "ABS: Demos" app and look for the "Tab Navigation" example and try with it.

**UPDATE**

Oh, I see...

So, try with the "ABS: Fragments" app. Here there is an example called "Tabs".

If you see its layout (fragment_tabs.xml), you can see every widget. You can wrap the `TabHost` with a new `LinearLayout` and add you `View` above the `TabHost`.

Change this:

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

For something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CHANGE ME FOR THE VIEW YOU WANT" />

    <TabHost 
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>
     </TabHost>
```

Comment: Ty for fast answer. I know for that example and its easy to implement. The problem is that i need image header above tabs and tabs needs to scroll up until they reach top and then stick there.

Comment: Ok, lets say that i put in tab content an listview with some items. The thing that i want to achive is: when user scroll that list, the textView that u named "change me for the view you want" should go out of the screen. When the user scroll all the way down it should come back.